# How do I create a table with foreign keys?

Tags: sql-server

I'm making a library database and I have a diagram of the tables drawn out [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uk03p.jpg) I've created all my tables that aren't dependent on any other tables first.

```
USE master
GO

/******Check to see if database exists******/
IF DB_ID('SET2133810') IS NOT NULL
    DROP DATABASE SET2133810
GO

/******Object: Database SET2133810******/
CREATE DATABASE SET2133810
GO

USE SET2133810
GO

/******Object: table*****/
CREATE TABLE BookList(
    BookID int IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    BookISBN varchar(20) NOT NULL,
    BookTitle varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    BookAuthor varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    BookPublisher varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    BookGenre varchar(50) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT PK_BookList PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (
    BookID ASC
 )
)
GO

/******Object: Table*****/
CREATE TABLE MembersList(
    MemberID int IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    MemberLName varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    MemberFName varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    MemberAddress varchar(50) NULL,
    MemberCity varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    MemberState char(2) NOT NULL,
    MemberZipCode varchar(20) NOT NULL,
    MemberPhone varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    MemberEmail varchar(50) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT PK_MembersList PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED(
    MemberID ASC
 )
)
GO

/******Object: table*****/
CREATE TABLE VendorsList(
    VendorID int IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    VendorName varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    VendorPhone varchar(50) NULL,
    VendorContactLName varchar(50) NULL,
    VendorContactFName varchar(50) NULL,
    VendorAddress varchar(50) NULL,
    VendorCity varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    VendorState char(2) NOT NULL,
    VendorZipCode varchar(20) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT PK_VendorsList PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (
    VendorID ASC
 )
)
GO

/******Object: Table*****/
CREATE TABLE InvoicesList(
    InvoiceID int IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    VendorID int NOT NULL,
    InvoiceNumber varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    InvoiceDate smalldatetime NOT NULL,
    InvoiceTotal money NOT NULL,
    PaymentTotal money NOT NULL,
    PaymentDate smalldatetime NULL,
 CONSTRAINT PK_InvoicesList PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED(
    InvoiceID ASC
 )
)
GO
```

I'm confused on how to code the booksIssued table and the InvoiceItems table since there are foreign keys in them, and I'd assume there needs to be some sort of explicit code that states this relationship.

I was able to get this far by copying a script from my textbook that creates a similar database. A couple of their tables I just straight up copied. And you'll see in my textbooks code below that they've created some tables with foreign keys. I'm just unsure on what code does what? and where the code is that identifies these relationships when the tables are being created.

```
USE master
GO

/****** Object:  Database AP     ******/
IF DB_ID('AP') IS NOT NULL
    DROP DATABASE AP
GO

CREATE DATABASE AP
GO 

USE AP
GO

/****** Object:  Table ContactUpdates  ******/   
CREATE TABLE ContactUpdates(
    VendorID int IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    LastName varchar(50) NULL,
    FirstName varchar(50) NULL
)
GO

/****** Object:  Table GLAccounts     ******/
CREATE TABLE GLAccounts(
    AccountNo int NOT NULL,
    AccountDescription varchar(50) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT PK_GLAccounts PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (
    AccountNo ASC
 )
)
GO

/****** Object:  Table InvoiceArchive     ******/
CREATE TABLE InvoiceArchive(
    InvoiceID int NOT NULL,
    VendorID int NOT NULL,
    InvoiceNumber varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    InvoiceDate smalldatetime NOT NULL,
    InvoiceTotal money NOT NULL,
    PaymentTotal money NOT NULL,
    CreditTotal money NOT NULL,
    TermsID int NOT NULL,
    InvoiceDueDate smalldatetime NOT NULL,
    PaymentDate smalldatetime NULL
) 
GO

/****** Object:  Table InvoiceLineItems     ******/
CREATE TABLE InvoiceLineItems(
    InvoiceID int NOT NULL,
    InvoiceSequence smallint NOT NULL,
    AccountNo int NOT NULL,
    InvoiceLineItemAmount money NOT NULL,
    InvoiceLineItemDescription varchar(100) NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT PK_InvoiceLineItems PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (
    InvoiceID ASC,
    InvoiceSequence ASC
 ) 
)
GO

/****** Object:  Table Invoices     ******/
CREATE TABLE Invoices(
    InvoiceID int IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    VendorID int NOT NULL,
    InvoiceNumber varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    InvoiceDate smalldatetime NOT NULL,
    InvoiceTotal money NOT NULL,
    PaymentTotal money NOT NULL,
    CreditTotal money NOT NULL,
    TermsID int NOT NULL,
    InvoiceDueDate smalldatetime NOT NULL,
    PaymentDate smalldatetime NULL,
 CONSTRAINT PK_Invoices PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (
    InvoiceID ASC
 )
)
GO

/****** Object:  Table Terms    ******/
CREATE TABLE Terms(
    TermsID int IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    TermsDescription varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    TermsDueDays smallint NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT PK_Terms PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (
    TermsID ASC
 )
) 
GO

/****** Object:  Table Vendors    ******/
CREATE TABLE Vendors(
    VendorID int IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    VendorName varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    VendorAddress1 varchar(50) NULL,
    VendorAddress2 varchar(50) NULL,
    VendorCity varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    VendorState char(2) NOT NULL,
    VendorZipCode varchar(20) NOT NULL,
    VendorPhone varchar(50) NULL,
    VendorContactLName varchar(50) NULL,
    VendorContactFName varchar(50) NULL,
    DefaultTermsID int NOT NULL,
    DefaultAccountNo int NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT PK_Vendors PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED(
    VendorID ASC
 )
) 
GO
```

Comment: There are no foreign keys defined in any of the SQL you show.

Comment: Please consult the [Official docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/create-foreign-key-relationships?view=sql-server-ver15) - which should always be your first port of call.

Comment: If the examples you copied actually use a smalldatetime datatype for a column like "duedate", then I suggest you find better source for example databases - such as the MS provided [World Wide Importers and AdventureWorks](https://github.com/Microsoft/sql-server-samples).

Comment: @DaleK I haven't made them yet, that's why I'm asking this question. If you look in the image of the database diagram. The BooksIssued table has two foreign keys(Book ID, MemberID). The InvoiveList has the foreign key vendorID and the InvoiceItems has the InvoiceID foreign Key

Comment: @SMor Why would that be an inappropriate data type? It would hold a date value

Comment: @Morph you said "And you'll see in my textbooks code below that they've created some tables with foreign keys." - my point is they didn't create any foreign keys. In future I recommend looking at the official docs first and only ask a question when you get stuck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You add Foreign Key Constraints in a similar manner to Primary Key Constraints inline in the [CREATE TABLE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-table-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) statement

```
CREATE TABLE Invoices(
    InvoiceID int IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    VendorID int NOT NULL,
    InvoiceNumber varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    InvoiceDate smalldatetime NOT NULL,
    InvoiceTotal money NOT NULL,
    PaymentTotal money NOT NULL,
    PaymentDate smalldatetime NULL,
 CONSTRAINT PK_Invoices 
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED(InvoiceID ASC),
 CONSTRAINT FK_Invoices_Vendors 
    FOREIGN KEY (VendorID) REFERENCES Vendors(VendorID)
 )
```

Or after the table is created with [ALTER TABLE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-table-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

```
 ALTER TABLE Invoices ADD CONSTRAINT FK_Invoices_Vendors
    FOREIGN KEY (VendorID) references Vendors(VendorID)
```

Note its bad practice to add `List` as a suffix or `tbl_` prefix to tables.  Singular or Plural nouns and noun phrases are both acceptable.  Although you should not mix singular and plural in a database.

Also its acceptable to type SQL keywords either in all lowercase or all caps, but again pick one and be consistent.

Comment: Thanks man, this really helped. One more question. reading through this example in my textbook I noticed that after the author creates these tables he hard codes in all the values/records. Including there Identity keys, and keeping track of each tables data as it relates to another table. This seems unnecessary I would imagine for my library database, the librarian wouldn't need to know these relationships and the data she entered would effect all related tables automatically. Is this functionality beyond T-SQL? Would I have to make an app from C# or JAVA to handle data input

Comment: Yes.  Entering sample data in TSQL scripts is commonly done only when designing, testing, or explaining the schema design, or for data that is expected to change very rarely.  Typically users would interact with an application to manage the data in the database.